# WebAPI Regex path attribute throws error "Replacement value for the token could not be found"

Tags: c#, regex, .net-core, webapi

In my .NEt Core 3 code I have defined a WebAPI route using the following parameter:

```cs
[HttpGet("ViewerRoles/{searchString:regex(^\\d+-(?<=-)[\\w ]*$)}")]
public async Task<ViewerRole> GetViewSettings(string searchString) {
    // ....
}
```

This throws me the following error when starting the service:

> Error: While processing template
>   'api/[controller]/ViewerRoles/{searchString:regex(^\d+-(?<=-)[\w
>   ]*$)}', a replacement value for the token '\w ' could not be found.
>   Available tokens: 'action, controller'. To use a '[' or ']' as a
>   literal string in a route or within a constraint, use '[[' or ']]'
>   instead."

I'm pretty confused. The Regex seems to be correct and works in various online testers. But why does it throw an error then?

Answer (score 2):

I already found the answer as I was reviewing it. The problematic part is `[\\w ]`. You have to use double square brackets. Otherwise the compiler will interpret it as a placeholder.

```cs
[HttpGet("ViewerRoles/{searchString:regex(^\\d+-(?<=-)[[\\w ]]*$)}")]
public async Task<ViewerRole> GetViewSettings(string searchString) {
    // ....
}
```